# Create envelope with document

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create a new envelope with a new document through the DocuSign Api.

According to the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create), I understand that I need to send a POST request to [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes).

But I haven't found an example how to add the document to the body of the request.

Can someone give me an code example? How exactly the body of the request should look like?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a link to examples, some using our SDKs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing)

The body of your JSON may look like this:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this document set",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "' > $request_data
            cat $doc1_base64 >> $request_data
            printf '",
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "documentId": "1"
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "carbonCopies": [
            {
                "email": "{USER_EMAIL}",
                "name": "Charles Copy",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            }
        ],
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "{USER_EMAIL}",
                "name": "{USER_FULLNAME}",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "/sn1/",
                            "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                            "anchorXOffset": "20",
                            "anchorYOffset": "10"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```